# What is a good way to lure animals / mobs into big holes/traps?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

It seems to me like the last few updates made animals/mobs smarter: they won't fall that easily into holes 2+ blocks deep. Maybe I'm mistaken, maybe not...

Anyway, did anyone try to combine normal blocks and stone slabs to create an angle which would produce more "jumps" into hole traps? Is there a proven combination of blocks that gives good results?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They still seem to like to *swim*, so you could make some [Water Traps](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Traps#Water_traps) - or any running water, maybe combined with a waterfall, into your pit.

Comment: Mobs don't actually like swimming, its just that when they fall in they find it hard to get out. Couple this with the fact that they don't recognise water very well (if at all) makes it look like they like swimming. This doesn't negate your idea of making water traps - just (hopefully) explains how they might work.

Answer (score 7):

Not very cheap, but it's a good tactic: combine some [pressure plates](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pressure_Plate) together with [dispensers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dispenser) filled with arrows or snowballs.

That way, whenever mobs get near the hole, the dispenser will fire at the mob, hopefully pushing it into the hole.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to lure animals, you need to use their breeding mechanics.

If you want to lure sheep, cows, and mooshrooms, use wheat.

If you want to lure pigs, use carrots.

If you want to lure chickens, use wheat seeds.

However, luring wolves and ocelots, first you gotta tame them.

Taming wolves is easy, all you have to do you use some skeleton bones.

Taming ocelots is a bit harder, because the ocelot will run away if you move your head or body a lot, it will run away, setting it to F8 mode will help a little bit.

Then to lure wolves and ocelots, just simply walk once you've tamed them and they will follow you around and stuff like that.

NPC Villagers

Villagers do not have a food item; they will breed of their own accord (and in their own time) depending on the available houses, or at least "registered doors". The only possible way to lure villagers is to get a few zombies to chase them into holes, while doing this, you may end up getting a few zombies in the trap too.

Answer (score 1):

Snowballs will make mobs act as if they have been hurt but don't cause any damage (they still flash red)

Not really luring more herding

Answer (score 1):

Place three blocks on top of each other, then break the two blocks underneath the top one. Place a wooden pressure plate underneath the floating block and place 4 wooden doors around the pressure plate, (each facing at a 90degree angle difference). When a mob triggers the pressure plate, all doors will close and you then proceed to kill it through the windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are holding wheat in your hand any animal will follow you, so you could just walk into your hole and they will follow and you can use a ladder to get out.

Comment: Animals can climb ladders too...